# Displaying records in the custom sequence

Tags: sql, database

I want to fetch data from the database in my custom sequence.
For example if the query is;

```
SQL>Select * from table1 where id in(5,3,4)
```

So expected result would be.

```
Id  | Name
----------
5   | John
3   | David
4   | Rock
```

but data is displaying in following order:

```
Id  | Name
----------
3   | David
4   | Rock
5   | John
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this result?

Comment: u can use order by??

Comment: The where-clause doesn't mean anything for the result-order. Use a CASE in the ORDER BY to get customized result-order.

Comment: There is no connection between the where clause and the order of result set , you have to use ORDER BY to get a specific order

Comment: It's quite easy to get the wanted result order for these 3 rows, but the real question is how to keep this order by requirement when more rows are added!

Answer (score 1):

The where clause is not relevant to the order of the results.

You can use "order by XXX" to arrange results by specific column/s,

but as I can see in your example it is not ordered by id or name.

So... I would suggest to add another column named "position" or "pos" and it will contain an integer with the desired order, than simple query with order by that column.

```
 select * 
 from table1
 where id in(5,3,4)
 order by position
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, it will give your wanted order

```
Select * from table1 where id=5
Union all
Select * from table1 where id=3
union all
Select * from table1 where id=4
```

Comment: May work well in many cases, the the only way to ensure an order is by having an ORDER BY clause...

Comment: he want order as 5,3,4 but not asc or desc correct it might be zigzag...@jarlh

Comment: Depends on the dbms... UNION ALL usually retains the order, but there's no guarantee at all.

Comment: in ssms mssql it will not order so i kept this and I dont know abt other